# fsck problem when booting Debian stretch

Tags: debian, tty, fsck

I tried to boot my PC and I had this problem

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sdb6 contains a file system with errors check forced.
/dev/sdb6: Unconnected directory inode 1076721 (/var/tmp/???)


/dev/sdb6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY.
           (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sdb6 requires a manual fsck
modprobe: module ehci-orion not found in modules.dep

BusyBox v.1.22.1 (Debian 1:1.22.0-15) build in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

/bin/sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
(initramfs)
```

So in early morning I had to mount my SATA (which is connected right to motherboard, Linux is by USB so its outer -- don't know how to describe it) and it have Windows 7 on that SATA. I had to copy my project and I had problem, couldn't mount it. I haven't time to solve that so I rebooted computer to use Windows 7 and didn't had problems. Now after school I tried to boot Linux and had this problem.

```
[    8.328785] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[    8.328799] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sdb6 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sdb6: Unconnected directory iinode 1076721 (/var/tmp/???)


/dev/sdb6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
         (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sdb6 requires a manual fsck
modprobe: module ehci-orion not found in modules.dep


BusyBox v1.22.1 (Debian 1:1.22.0-15) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
(initramfs) _
```

Comment: What is Ubuntu Stretch? Do you mean Debian Stretch (testing)?

Answer (score 1):

The immediate fix is to type `fsck /dev/sdb6`. It should ask you (hopefully not too many questions) about what you want to do to fix the filesystem. That's what it means by "RUN fsck MANUALLY". You could also run `fsck -y /dev/sdb6` if you just want it to say yes to everything. Note that fsck is very slightly dangerous; if you have critical data on that drive and don't have a backup, then you'll first want to make an image copy of the drive.

You will probably wind up with some files/directories in `lost+found`, you'll need to check if those files are anything important and then either move them back to where they belong (possibly changing ownership as well) or delete them. Note that `lost+found` is typically only accessible to root.

Hopefully once you regain access to the system, you can check the kernel log or syslog to see why it broke—e.g., it's possible the drive developed a bad sector, which happened to hit some filesystem metadata.

Answer (score 0):

you should reinstall your desktop. 
prees ctrl+alt+f1 or some Fi (i<7)

login with your user and pass.

Write in terminal:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session`

Also, see this bug report that solve problem by upgrading :

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/552018